# Sharing web.config transforms between multiple projects in the same solution

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, web-config, csproj, web.config-transform

We have a web.Release.config file we would like to share between multiple AspNetCore projects in the same solution. At the time of writing we have 18 apps we would like to execute the exact same set of transformations on. However just putting the web.Release.Config file in a shared project does not seem to execute the transformations.

Is there any way it can be done directly in the project/solution model, or is our only option to do some copy scripting in our CI?

Comment: You can add the transformation steps to your MSBuild files by-hand. Look at the web.config-specific `.targets` files in your Visual Studio installation folder to see how to do it.

Comment: That still sounds like I need to do it for all projects?

Comment: Yes-and-no. You will need to define the common/shared transformation logic in a new custom MSBuild `.targets` file, but after that's done you just need to reference that `.targets` file from each project's MSBuild files which is a 1-line change in each `.csproj` or `.pubxml` file.

Comment: Right... Not exactly what I hoped for. I'll see if I can't fiddle something in our CI system instead :/. But thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: VS itself does not have this function, you can customize some scripts to achieve it.